# Can't access the global ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When I try to get the data from the AspNetUserClaims I get an exception saying "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext". I'm not exactly sure why this happens all I want to do is make a table for AspNetUserClaims so I can edit them in the admin panel.

Method to generate table based on database:

```
public IActionResult Claim()
        {
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var allclaims = context.UserClaims.ToList();
            var table = "";
            var cur = "odd";
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var claim in allclaims)
            {
                cur = i % 2 != 0 ? "odd" : "even";
                table +=$"<tr role=\"row\" class=\"{cur}\">" +
                        "<td class=\"sorting_1\">{claim.UserId}</td>" +
                        $"<td>{claim.ClaimType}</td>" +
                        $"<td>{claim.ClaimValue}</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
            }
            ViewBag.Table = table;
            return View();
        }
```

If anybody experienced understands this issue I would be appreciative of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by experimenting.
I resolved my issue by adding the following code to my AdminController : Controller class. This allowed me to query using the `_context` object.

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public AdminController(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```